# How to change icons in ActionBar dynamically

Tags: java, android, menu

I want to change the icon on the ActionBar dynamically,I have a exit menu.But It doesn't change my android phone in the 5 version

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.exit_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit_menu:
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

> This is my exit menu xml.

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:id="@+id/exit_menu"
                android:icon="@drawable/exit"
                android:title="Exit"
               />       
        </menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2:
in onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)

```
MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.exit_menu);
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.new_icon);
```

xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit_menu"
        android:title="@string/menu_string"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateOptionsMenu method use

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(drawable);
```

Comment: Unfortunately,It doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.exit_menu);


        if (SOME CONDITION) {
            settingsItem.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_image));
        } else {
           settingsItem.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_image1));
        }
        settingsItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                //ONCLICK METHOD
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

do not handle in onOptionsItemSelected() method.

Comment: What is SOME CONDITION and settingsItem?

Comment: first settingItem is MenuItem, and second (SOME CONDITION) on base this, you can change your menu icon

Comment: SOME CONDITION means [ i==5 or string.equalsto("hey") ]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Toolbar instead of the ActionBar you can customize it a lot more. For example you can use a custom xml layout file for your Toolbar, making it look just how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just added one line to change icon in option menu. `item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));`

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.exit_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit_menu:
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                //Add This line in your code
                item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                System.exit(1);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @EmreAslan I also tried in API 24. It is working fine. Maybe you have other issues. Have you added app:showAsAction="always" in your menu item file ? Also, Can you send a screenshot of your layout?